# How to rsync a remote folder with updated files with a local folder that is also updated?

Tags: rsync

I rsynced a folder from an old server to a new  server.

Now I want to do it again after a few days, the problem is that both folders (new and old) have been updated by this point. Their files were updated differently, some new folders (different on both) inside the rsynced folder were created...

Now I want the new server to have the same folder as the old server but I don't want to rm the folder and rsync again because it has a lot of GBs.

Is "--update" sufficient here?

Comment: No, that will prevent old server from overwriting new server for files where new server has newer mod date.

Comment: What about running rsync --delete then running --ignore-existing then --update?

Comment: Please give more detail on what do you mean by "have the same folder"

Comment: The same as in when they were first synced up. Lets say the folder had 10GB. The new folder got 1gb od data (maybe some files like logs were increased too) and the old got 0.5 or 1.5gb. So the new data on old and new is different. Now I want to sync up again but without transmitting 10GB again. Esseantialy like I rm -rf the entire folder and synced up again.